# Admin page Product gallery livewire full page multi image upload

Tags: laravel-livewire, livewires

I'm trying to make a product gallery for the e-commerce page on the admin side, while uploading bulk products, the row in the table provides two times again.

```
 $this->validate([
'title' => 'required',
'NewsImage.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
'product_id' => 'required',
]);

 if(!empty($this->NewsImage)) {
        foreach ($this->NewsImage as $image) {
            $imageName = $image->hashName();
            $image->store('public/products');
            Image::create([
                'title' => $this->title,
                'image' => $imageName,
                'product_id' => $this->product_id,
            ]);
        }
    }
    $this->modalFormVisible = false;
    $this->reset();
    $this->resetFields();
```

```
 @if(count($NewsImage))
   @foreach($NewsImage as $image)
     <td class="px-6 py-4 text-sm whitespace-no-wrap">
<img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full" src="{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::url($Image->image) }}" />
 </td>
   @endforeach

  @endif
```

I want to list it side by side but I couldn't do it can you help me thank you very much in advance

[image]

I shared a related photo, I'm trying to sort the image side by side, but when I add it, it adds an extra row.